# URL Rewrite: from .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, iis

I'm here again, and this time with something I don't know, since I'm never using it. It's about .htaccess.

It's getting converted for IIS, but I think the fail is from my .HTACCESS line. I'm talking about the following line;

```
RewriteRule ^ref([^.]+)$ /quickregister/start?ref=$1
```

The Result I want is `http://example.com/ref/VALUE1`. However, this Rule gives me this; A `404 Error`

```
Requested URL      http://example.com:80/quickregister/start?ref=/VALUE1.php
Physical Path      C:\inetpub\wwwroot\quickregister\start
```

Comment: What do you mean by "The Result I want is..."? Is the "Requested URL" you've given literally the URL you are requesting (which is what you are saying) or the resulting URL after it has been rewritten? If it's the "Requested URL", then the `RewriteRule` directive you've posted above is not doing anything.

Comment: It's not doing it, the link http://example.com/ref/VALUE it should link to http://example.com/quickregister/start?ref=VALUE, but it shows me a 404.

Comment: According to the directive above, `/ref/VALUE` would be _internally rewritten_ to `/quickregister/start?ref=/VALUE` - note the slash. Do you want the slash or not (you have given examples both with and without)? Do you have other directives in your .htaccess file? Try changing it to an _external redirect_ to make sure that directive is being processed. ie. add `[R,L]` at the end of that directive. Note that you do not have the `L` flag in your current directive, so any later directives will be processed and possibly override this one.

Comment: I don't want the slash, because He needs to go to start.php, with the GET variable REF. With the Backslash, IIS doesn't recognize it as link, because it sees the file name as ref=/value1.php, not start.php with the var.

Comment: If you don't want the slash in the substitution then remove it from the captured group. eg. `^ref/([^.]+)$`. But if "He needs to go to `start.php`", why are you rewritting to `start`? "With the Backslash, IIS doesn't recognize it as link" - these are (forward) slashes, not backslashes. If it sees the filename as `ref=/value1.php` then it's not interpreting the query string correctly. At what point is this being converted into IIS (web.config?) directives? Or is this .htaccess file being processed directly by IIS using something like [Helicon Ape](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/)?

Comment: Hello, I Think you're not really getting the point, when the link should be http://example.com/ref/VALUE, you need the slash after ref and for ref. But, like you see, it makes an slash in the variable, and that's not what I want.

Comment: You're right, I'm "not really getting the point". However, removing the slash from the captured sub pattern (as I just mentioned) would seem to satisfy the requirement you've just mentioned. ie. Change the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ to `^ref/([^.]+)$` and then `example.com/ref/VALUE` would be rewritten to `example.com/quickregister/start?ref=VALUE` (no slash).